# MayAVI crashes under Python 3.6 (Anaconda)

Tags: python, pyqt4, anaconda, python-3.6, mayavi

I am using Python 3.6 (Anaconda distribution) under Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). I have been trying to animate some plots using MayAVI, but the code crashes.

The error message that I get is the following:

```
ImportError: Could not import backend for traits
_______________________________________________________________________________
Make sure that you have either the TraitsBackendWx or the TraitsBackendQt
projects installed. If you installed Mayavi with easy_install, try
easy_install <pkg_name>. easy_install Mayavi[app] will also work.

If you performed a source checkout, be sure to run 'python setup.py install'
in Traits, TraitsGUI, and the Traits backend of your choice.

Also make sure that either wxPython or PyQT is installed.
wxPython: http://www.wxpython.org/
PyQT: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro

ERROR: Module: main could not be imported
```

But I did installed Mayavi[app] using pip:

```
conda install pip
pip install mayavi[app]
```

I also tried several others solutions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960672/how-to-install-mayavi-trait-backends) and [this one](https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/483), but I always get the very same error message.

I also tried to install using conda:

```
conda install mayavi
```

But I get this error message:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - mayavi -> apptools 4.2.0 -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.6*
```

Is there any idea of how can I solve this?

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: Running `which pip` and `which python` will give you a clear idea and the readers which ones are getting executed. And running `conda env list`.

Comment: I get the correct Python path and pip (/home/USER/anaconda/bin/python)